# Trying to set variable to SQL result, variable is set to single letter

Tags: php, mysql

I've ran into this problem once before on a separate project and had to remove the issue all together.

Essentially what is happening is that I am querying my database and retrieving a few items

```
$techEm = mysql_query("SELECT `44aae_meiadmin_customers`.`support_email`, `44aae_meiadmin_customers`.`telephone`, `44aae_meiadmin_customers`.`company`, `44aae_users`.`name`, `44aae_users`.`email` 
FROM `44aae_meiadmin_customers`
INNER JOIN `44aae_users` on `44aae_meiadmin_customers`.`fk_user_id` = `44aae_users`.`id`
WHERE `fk_user_id` = ".$user->id);
```

Then I am assigning those items to variables

```
$techEm         =   mysql_fetch_assoc($techEm); 

$usersName  =   $techEm['name'];
$companyName =  $techEm['company'];
$techEm     =   $techEm['support_email'];
$usersEmail =   $techEm['email'];
$usersPhone =   $techEm['telephone'];
```

All of these variables are set correctly EXCEPT for `$usersPhone`.  This variable is set to "1231231234" in the database but when I echo it simply outputs "c"

Just to answer a few questions that may come up: the sql query works fine and pulls the information correctly through mysql.  There is nothing else overwriting the variable between when it is set and when it is outputted.

If anyone has any further information on this issue, it would be much appreciated!

*--Vico*

Comment: what is the field type in sql for 'telephone'?

Comment: Could it be a data type error? All the others are strings, but '1231231234' looks numeric.

Comment: All of the fields are set as varchars

Comment: Ah nevermind I realized I was overwriting the mysql array.  Apologies for the time waste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting your DB results in the line

```
$techEm     =   $techEm['support_email'];
```

From that point, you lose your results!

Change your variable name

```
$techEmail     =   $techEm['support_email'];
```

Comment: Yeah I had noticed that too.  I suppose its about time for another cup of coffee.  Thanks!